# Из строки (путь) получить объект

Tags: java, классы, строки

```
class A {
    static String a = "1", b = "2";
}
class B {
    String path = "ru.A.a";
    ...
    // Как получить значение a через строку?
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Вам не должно хотеться такого. Скорее всего, вы делаете что-то неправильно. Java — это не PHP, у неё другие выразительные средства. Какая ваша настоящая задача?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Class<A> clazz = Class.forName("ru.A");
A object = clazz.newInstance();
System.out.println(A.a);
```

так?